# Cannot retrieve an expected document from Solr while filtering by date

Tags: date, solr

I can't actually retrieve a document from Solr. I submitted it like this:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="date_online">2012-02-09T19:46:00Z</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

The `date_online` field is filled in with the current date, its type definition in the `schema.xml` is the following:

```
<field name="date_online" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

After I submitted the document and released a commit command, when I search with `q=*:*` and `fq=date_online:[* TO NOW/MINUTE]` I can't retrieve the document I just submitted. Of course there must be a problem with the date, but I already checked the time on the server and is correct, furthermore I've been able to reproduce the problem locally as well.

Does anybody know why I can't retrieve that document? Why doesn't it match my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was of course the date! I found out I could retrieve the document only one hour later, so I figured it out. Solr uses UTC for time and I was sending the date and time for my actual timezone (GMT+1), that's why I could get the document only one hour later. In fact, it's required to convert the time to UTC format before submitting it to Solr.

Let's say for example it's 6 o'clock GMT+1, for Solr it's simply 5 o'clock (UTC). If you send a document with a date field containing for example `2012-02-09T18:00:00Z` (that date doesn't contain any information about the timezone) for Solr it's 6 o'clock UTC. If you filter on that date like me you'll see that document only one hour later. The right way converting the date to UTC (`2012-02-09T17:00:00Z` in this case) before sending the document to Solr.